# Using "sockets" how can I find a server if I don't know its address?

Tags: c++, objective-c, visual-c++

Using "sockets", I am writing an Apps in Visual C++ and for iPhone to communicate with each other.  Since I know the IP address I can set it and everything works fine.  But if a user doesn't know the IP address, how can they find it or connect to a server on a port?

Comment: Do you mean resolve a host name? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need some kind of service discovery protocol.  [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) or [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) are examples.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the exact purpose of the Domain Name Service protocol - aka DNS